# react duplicated item when removed from useState

Tags: arrays, reactjs, use-state

I try to make a reservation app for my end year project. I don't know why I can add an item in the state but when I try to remove it and add it again it got duplicated. I made a lot of research but didn't find responses.

here the problem :

[image]

and here is my code :

```
    const [js, setJs] = useState([]);

    const addPlace = (target) => {
    let selectedPlace = document.getElementById(target.id);
    const temporary = js;

    const placeAjouteeASelection = {
      id: target.id,
      key: `${target.id} ${dateUtilisee} ${heureDebutUtilisee} ${heureFinUtilisee}`,
      nom: target.id.split('Place')[1],
      date: dateUtilisee,
      heureDebutUtilisee: heureDebutUtilisee,
      heureFinUtilisee: heureFinUtilisee,
    };

    switch (selectedPlace.getAttribute('fill')) {
      case couleurPlaceReservee:
        alert('place reservée !');
        break;
      case couleurPlaceSelectionnee:
        const toBeDeleted = selectedPlace.id;
        selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceDisponible);
        setJs(js.filter((item) => item.id !== toBeDeleted));
        break;
      case couleurPlaceDisponible:
        selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceSelectionnee);
        temporary.push(placeAjouteeASelection);
        setJs([...temporary]);
        break;
      default:
        selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceDisponible);
        break;
    }
    console.log('TEMPORARY', temporary);
  };
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT:**

Okay I tried your solution, but now when you remove an element from the array it remove everything, any idea ? I tried to use filter array.

Here a small gif and my code :

```
    switch (selectedPlace.getAttribute('fill')) {
  case couleurPlaceReservee:
    alert('place reservée !');
    break;
  case couleurPlaceSelectionnee:
    const toBeDeleted = selectedPlace.id;
    selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceDisponible);
    const list = js.filter((item) => item.id !== toBeDeleted);
    setJs(list);
    break;
  case couleurPlaceDisponible:
    selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceSelectionnee);
    setJs((prev) => {
      return [...prev, placeAjouteeASelection];
    });
    break;
  default:
    selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceDisponible);
    break;
}
```

into render function :

```
     {js &&
    js.map((a) => {
      return <li key={a.key}>{a.nom}</li>;
    })}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the up-to-date state variable

```
case couleurPlaceDisponible:
        selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceSelectionnee);
        temporary.push(placeAjouteeASelection);
        setJs(temporary => {return [...temporary]});
        break;

case couleurPlaceSelectionnee:
        const toBeDeleted = selectedPlace.id;
        selectedPlace.setAttribute('fill', couleurPlaceDisponible);
        js.splice(toBeDeleted, 1);
        setJs([...js])
        break;
```

Comment: thanks for help, one part of my problem has been solved but now there is the other part with the removing of an element, I tried a lot of solutions but, don't found out where is the problem

Comment: I've edited the answer again, let me know if it helps

Comment: thanks, but unfortunetly same behavour, it return me an empty state array, I tried to look into the index returned by splice method, i got -1 because "js" is empty ! I don't know why. Like if react set the js state to empty. if you add some seat its okey but when you try to remove it it set the state to empty

Comment: try to do the same way in terms of delete, use up-to-date state